# SWRevealViewController side menu is not working in swift 3

Tags: ios, iphone, swift3

I am using `SWRevealViewController` for side menu functionality. Its working fine but whenever I have added the following code in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method. side menu is not working for first time launch.

> How to solve this problem??

this is my Code :

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {


   // UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()

  //  IQKeyboardManager.sharedManager().enable = true


    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)

    guard UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "IsFirstTime") != nil  else {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "IsFirstTime")

        self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)

        let storyboard = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LaunchViewController") as! LaunchViewController
        let navigationController = UINavigationController.init(rootViewController: viewController)
        self.window?.rootViewController = navigationController

        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()





        return true
    }

    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SWRevealViewController") as! SWRevealViewController
   // let navigationController = UINavigationController.init(rootViewController: viewController)
    self.window?.rootViewController = viewController

    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()





    return true
}
```

Thank you

Comment: SWRevealViewController is the side menu , in here add your main page

Comment: LaunchViewController also coming but side menu(UIBarButtonItem) is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you are making `LaunchViewController` initial VC on first launch. That's why it is not working at first time.

To use `SWRevealViewController` you need two view controller, one is front view controller which you want to show first time and second is for drawer which maybe `tableViewController` that contains all other view controller. To add `SWRevealViewController` call `openDrawer()` in `AppDelegate`.

```
func openDrawer() {

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)
    let drawerVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "idDrawerVC") as! RearVC
    let dashboardVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "idFrontVC") as! FrontVC
    let frontNavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: dashboardVC)

    let revealViewController = SWRevealViewController(rearViewController: drawerVC, frontViewController: frontNavigationController)
    revealViewController?.delegate = self
    revealViewController?.view.backgroundColor = .clear
    revealViewController?.modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve
    window?.rootViewController = revealViewController
}
```